# Exception while trying to connect to IBM MQ using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

I have a Java application built with Springboot and Apache camel. When trying to run the application it gives an exception that confuses me. In the examples that I'm using I don't see anything related to this exceptionListener, but maybe someone here could help and explain what is going wrong?

This is my code:

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.CommonConstants;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
        @Bean
        public JmsComponent mq() {
            JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
            jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
            return jmsComponent;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
            try {
                
                String keystoreKey = "${keyStorePassword}";
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                keyStore.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("${keyStore}"),
                        keystoreKey.toCharArray());
    
                // Create key manager
                KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keystoreKey.toCharArray());
                KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
    
                // Create trust manager
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
                TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    
                // Initialize SSLContext
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
                sslContext.init(km, tm, null);
                SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    
                MQEnvironment.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return  mqQueueConnectionFactory;
        }
    }
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mq' defined in class path resource [nl/rabobank/mqputter/JmsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent]: Factory method 'mq' threw exception with message: javax/jms/ExceptionListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
    at nl.rabobank.mqputter.MqPutterApplication.main(MqPutterApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent]: Factory method 'mq' threw exception with message: javax/jms/ExceptionListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/ExceptionListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent.createConfiguration(JmsComponent.java:1260) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-M3.jar!/:4.0.0-M3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent.<init>(JmsComponent.java:76) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-M3.jar!/:4.0.0-M3]
    at nl.rabobank.mqputter.JmsConfiguration.mq(JmsConfiguration.java:47) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at nl.rabobank.mqputter.JmsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$mq$0(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at nl.rabobank.mqputter.JmsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at nl.rabobank.mqputter.JmsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.mq(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.ExceptionListener
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Edit:

Here are the dependencies:

```
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot 3, which is for JakartaEE, whilst you are still use IBM MQ libraries that are JavaEE. So either find a JakartaEE version of the IBM MQ libraries or downgrade to Spring Boot 2.7.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your answer. Your explanation is clear! Only wondering how did you notice that? So that I can also see it in future cases. I've also added my pom dependencies in the question above

Comment: `javax.jms` is from JavaEE, your stacktrace shows Spring version 6.0.10 which is used by Spring Boot 3+ and is JakartaEE. Also if tha tis your pom you are doing it wrong, never mix jars from different versions of a framework (here `spring-jms`) as that will inevitably lead to weird to debug situations!

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for clearing that up. What confuses me is that the documentation says that the libraries that I am using are for JakartaEE. To make it more clear I've added the libraries that I'm currently using - 
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=messaging-mq-classes-jakarta-overview

Comment: Upon second look the problem is your old camel version which isn't JakartaEE. It is also some old milestone which I hope you didn't really use on your live system. You should upgrade that to a newer JakartaEE version as well (and remove the spring-jms dependency as that is incompatible as well, never mix modules from different versions of a framework!)>

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your help. It was resolved by removing the spring-jms dependency. So I guess this was a hard lesson on why to never mix them. Thanks!